# Ruby script to automate browser actions/connect to WiFi

Tags: ruby, wifi

I have a Pi 3 that I'd like to setup once and do zero config/maintenance on it thereafter. So far I have the working program, a script setup to run automatically on boot (to handle power disconnects/etc.), and now I would like to automate internet connection (to handle wifi disconnects, etc.)

The wifi chip is on the pi 3, however to get internet connectivity you have to open a browser and accept terms/conditions every time you reconnect. I am wondering if there is a way within ruby coding to basically check for internet connection, and if there is no connection then to open the browser, click accept, then check again and continue.

Comment: You won't be able to script a browser, but I bet you can do this with [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize).

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, there are two main browser automation frameworks:

[Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and [Watir](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver).
Both were initially created for testing your own apps, but can also be used in normal code.

To my experience, Watir tends to be faster and is more object oriented, therefore I use it when I'm writing some larger drivers, however Capybara is easier to script and better to read.